# How to keep images and pods in podman while switching between rootful and rootless?

Tags: podman, rootless

I started with podman (rootful=false) and created a pod with two images in it.
I want to switch to a rootful podman to have more network capabilities.

However, when I run `podman machine set --rootful=true`, my pod disappears . After reverting back, it reappears.

How can I move the pod between the two states (rootless, rootful)?

Comment: You need to delete the rootless pods and then re-deploy them into rootful podman.